# How to get the index value while using ko.utils.arrayForEach

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using `ko.utils.arrayForEach` as mentioned below.

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(comments , function(comment) {
    tmp.push(comment);
});
```

Here I am getting all the results and they are pushed to `tmp`. If I want to access the first record alone, how can I modify the above code for retrieving the index.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible yet. PimTerry added this functionnality on December (see this [commit](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/commit/4c2387a17d4a0eb6f8673890ee59a48c79a31e9c)), but it has not be release yet.

Until now; you can do it manually:

```
for (var i = 0, j = comments.length; i < j; i++) {
  // use an anonymous function to keep the same code structure
  (function(comment, i) {
    tmp.push(comment);
    // do what you need with i here
  })(comments[i], i);
}
```

It's exaclty the code used inside `ko.utils.arrayForEach`. The migration will be very easy once Knockout will be released

Comment: For those coming to this question looking for a current answer, the correct usage with respect to receiving the item index is: 
`ko.utils.arrayForEach(comments, function(comment, index) { ... });`

Answer (score 20):

Since version 3.1.0 released on 14 May 2014, `index` is passed to all the array functions as the second argument:

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(items, function(item, index) {
    /* ... */
});
```